# Value of type 'ImagePicker' has no member 'contentMode'

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, imagepicker

I'm trying to use contentMode like listed below but I don't understand why I receive the following error:

Cannot infer contextual base in reference to member 'scaleAspectFit'
Value of type 'ImagePicker' has no member 'contentMode'

```
           if let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
               parent.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit    <--- Error
               parent.image = uiImage
           }
           
           parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
       }
   }
```

Any hints?
Thank you!

attached you find the full code:

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
    @Binding var image: UIImage?
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let picker = UIImagePickerController()
        picker.delegate = context.coordinator
        picker.allowsEditing = true
        
    //    picker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
        return picker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ImagePicker>) {}
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        let parent: ImagePicker
        
        init(_ parent: ImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let uiImage = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.editedImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.image.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
                parent.image = uiImage
            }
            
            parent.presentationMode.wrappedValue.dismiss()
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(self)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `contentMode`  property

```
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
   @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
   @Binding var image: UIImage? 
   @Binding var mode:UIView.ContentMode? // here
```

Then

```
parent.mode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Thank you! That is the solution! :-)